# I have a round red icon with a minus in it on the top of the screen

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, icons

I recently faced that error that when I click on that icon it says

[image]

I tried to remove wine through the terminal since I don't need it anymore and that's what it says

[image]

I wrote configure wine because that's how it is called when I pass the cursor over it. I tried to just write wine but it said it would remove about 3GB so I didn't know what it is. here's a screenshot:

[image]

[image]

I didn't press Y.

So how to get rid of the problem?
Please help

Comment: Instead of posting pictures, please copy the text from your terminal and post the text into the question.  Open a terminal window, and enter the command `sudo apt update` and edit your question to include the output of that command, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the wine1.6 package and run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed. You have several Linux kernel versions that can be removed with `sudo apt autoremove` and removing one kernel version will free up almost 300MB of additional disk space, so that amounts to a lot of additional disk space if you have several kernel versions that can be removed.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove wine1.6  
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked though not exactly as you said. Only with the first command it already let me remove it . I just pressed Y and it removed it. I restarted the computer and I don't see it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bug [package manager bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/1420390) update-notifier doesn't cope with multiarch packages installed.  Do join the bug (click on button at the "Does this affect me?" question at the top of the bug.  There is no 64 bit package so named, just a 32 bit one, and that confuses the package manager.